# Getting specific field values from a JSON using Python

Tags: python, json

I am pulling out a collection of devices that are downed on our network.

I am running:

```
rjson = r.json()
print(json.dumps(rjson, indent = 5))
```

And it returns:

```
{
     "paging": {
          "size": 13
     },
     "data": {
          "devices": [
               {
                    "hostName": "host_1",
                    "networkAddress": "111.111.111.111",
                    "bestState": "Down",
                    "worstState": "Down",
               },
               {
                    "hostName": "host_2",
                    "networkAddress": "111.111.111.111",
                    "bestState": "Down",
                    "worstState": "Down",
               },
               {
                    "hostName": "host_3",
                    "networkAddress": "111.111.111.111",
                    "bestState": "Down",
                    "worstState": "Down",
               },
```

I would like to run though this json and create a list with each hostName that is returned. How would I do this?

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: As a new user, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your task, decode the JSON and extract the relevant info from the data.

Comment: [Here](https://pythonspot.com/json-encoding-and-decoding-with-python/) just a quick google search away from your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
from operator import itemgetter

host_names = list(map(itemgetter('hostName'), rjson['data']['devices']))

print(host_names)
```

output:

```
['host_1', 'host_2', 'host_3']
```